# Compare top two rows and identify columns whose values are different in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table with few columns and the table contains multiple rows with same values (for few fields only). Here am attached my table .

```
Id  EmpName ProjectName ChargeDesc  CostCenter  Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul 
32  2487    1386           124030   017N         0   0  0   0   0   3   0   
33  2487    1386           124030   017N         0   0  0   0   0   3   3
```

Like above image here is my requirement.

I want to get top 2 rows with where condition as follows (empname, projname, chargedesc, costcenter) and created date as desc.

Here I want to compare these 2 rows and find the differences of columns with values.

So example in above image all fields are same values except Jul column.
So I want output like Jul column with 3 as value.

Here am using **SQL Server 2019** version

Comment: FYI, this would likely be *far* easier with a normalised design.

Answer (score 1):

You can unpivot and aggregate:

```
select empname, projname, chargedesc, costcenter, mon,
       min(val), max(val)
from t cross apply
     (values ('Jan', jan), ('Feb', feb), . . . 
     ) v(mon, val)
group by empname, projname, chargedesc, costcenter, mon
having min(val) <> max(val);
```